# Golang http server blocks when starts a goroutine of infinite-loop

Tags: http, go, block, goroutine

As i learned from golang docs, if i set runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8) with a cpu of 8 cores (intel  i7), then start a goroutine of infinite-loop, other gorutines should not be blocked because there are engough threads and goprocs. But this is not true when using net/http package, an infinite-loop goroutine will block http server after a few invocations.
Can anyone help to explain why ?

1. If i comment the line of "go infinite loop", start client after server, client will output 1000 asterisks; but if i enable the goroutine, client will block after print a few asterisks
2. I have tried add runtime.LockOSThread() in the goroutine, it seems that doesn't work
3. My Environment: osx 10.10, go version go1.3.1 darwin/amd64

**Server code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
)

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("hello"))
}

func infiniteloop() {
    for {

    }
}

func main() {
    // set max procs for multi-thread executing
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    // print GOMAXPROCS=8 on my computer
    fmt.Println("GOMAXPROCS=", runtime.GOMAXPROCS(-1))
    http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(myHandler))

    // uncomment below line cause server block after some requests 
    // go infiniteloop()
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8280", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

**Client code:**

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func getOnce() {
    if resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8280"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    } else {
        defer func() {
            if err := resp.Body.Close(); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }()
        if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
            fmt.Println("error codde:", resp.StatusCode)
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Print("*")

        }
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        getOnce()
        if i%50 == 0 {
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }

}
```

---

Now i know why such emtpy loop block other goroutines, but  why `runtime.LockOSThread()` doesn't help either?

```golang
func infiniteloop() {
    // add LockOSThread will not help
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    for {
    }
}
```

As http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread mentioned, the empty loop should be executed in an standalone thread, and other goroutines should not be impacted by the busy loop. What's wrong in my understanding?

Comment: An "infinite" loop isn't a problem. It's a busy loop that does nothing but burn CPU that's a problem.

Comment: @Grzegorz Żur  Are you sure the client can print all 1000 asterisks? I have cross-compiled the source files and run them on an linux/amd64 platform. The client printed about 150 asterisks before halted

Comment: @user922965 My mistake, I run it with critical line commented out. I redone the test and it blocks.

Comment: I get the same halts, which is unexpected, must be a limitation of the scheduler somehow?  Maybe file a bug report :)

Comment: I run the code with version go1.4beta1 linux/amd64 and it have not printed a single character. :-( I think it is a good question for [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Go runtime's scheduler [is not fully pre-emptive at this time](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=543).  Go 1.2 improved matters [by occasionally calling into the scheduler on function calls](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption), but the infinite loops in your example have no function calls so this doesn't help.

With an actual body to your infinite loop handlers, you may see better behaviour.  Alternatively, a manual call to [`runtime.Gosched`](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) may help in cases like this.

Comment: I add one more question of LockOfThread, can you give more advices?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to describe what you're trying to do exactly.  Surely you aren't using empty infinite loops in your real program, so what exactly is it you want to know?

Comment: I am trying to compare http performance between golang and java nio, this is an edge case that some cores are exhausted by other applications and can not be used by http server. Your links have resolved my question actually, i just wonder why "LockOSThread" doesn't work, and try to get more knowledge of golang scheduler.

Comment: I'm not sure if `LockOSThread` actually allocates another thread for running Go code on or not.  If it doesn't, then it wouldn't help here.  If you want to experiment with reducing the number of cores your app runs on for testing, perhaps look at your OS's CPU affinity features.  On Linux, the `taskset` utility might do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

The scheduler might not be able to preempt such an empty "infinite" loop. The scheduler got better and better during the last release, maybe he *should* be good enough for such code; he definitely is good enough for real code. Just don't do such nonsense.