# Strange behaviour with SMTP within goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm puzzled by some strange behaviour I found using SMTP from within a goroutine.

When trying to send an email using the following code, my SendMail function starts (I can see a log message) but never completes. It just hangs.

```
func main() {
    go SendEmail("TEST")
    for {}
  }
```

However, when I add another call to SendMail - two emails are both sent successfully.

```
func main() {
    go SendEmail("TEST")
    SendEmail("TEST")
    for {}
  }
```

Can anybody explain what is going on?

*NB this is a very simplified version of a scheduled task, hence the while loop*

Code to send email:

```
func SendEmail(message string) {
  log.Print("Sending email")
  from, password, to := "me@gmail.com", "PASSWORD", "me@gmail.com"

  err := smtp.SendMail(
    "smtp.gmail.com:587",
    smtp.PlainAuth("", from, password, "smtp.gmail.com"),
    from,
    []string{to},
    []byte(message),
    )
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
  log.Print("Sending complete")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add `runtime.Gosched()` into the empty for loop?

Comment: Try replacing `for {}` with `select {}`. It's probably a scheduler issue, which I'm sure someone else will explain in more detail :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang http server blocks when starts a goroutine of infinite-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624959/golang-http-server-blocks-when-starts-a-goroutine-of-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace your `for{}` with a `select{}`. Never create an empty `for{}`.

The `for{}` creates a loop that spins forever, but because there are no function calls (or more accurately stack checks and/or allocations) in the loop, the scheduler will never be able to deschedule the main goroutine, which in turn prevents your other goroutine from being scheduled. (This will also probably eat a whole CPU, because your busy-looping a OS Thread)

See my note about GOMAXPROCS at the end.

By calling `SendEmail("TEST")` right after your `go SendEmail("TEST")` the runtime gets a chance (or rather, multiple chances) to schedule your other goroutine to run, before getting to your `for{}` loop.

Using an empty select (`select{}`) instead, the main goroutine will wait indefinitely without consuming any CPU and instead will yield directly to the scheduler.

**About GOMAXPROCS**

If your GOMAXPROCS is 1 (default before Go 1.5) you will only have a single OS thread (at least for running goroutines), which will prevent any other goroutines from running, if you have a busy-loop. If you have GOMAXPROCS > 1 the runtime could still schedule other goroutines, as there is more than one thread for running goroutines, but you shouldn't rely on that. Instead, you should remove any busy-loops.